# Putting border around a spinner

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm looking into putting a border around my spinner. I've set up an XML file for it but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure it's something simple as usual.

Activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_time_iv"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_time_48dp" />
        <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_time_spinner"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            app:ms_text_color="@android:color/white"
            app:ms_background_color="@android:color/background_dark"
            app:ms_dropdown_height="300dp"
            />
```

dropdown_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<corners android:radius="6dip" />
<stroke
    android:color="@color/white"
    android:width="@dimen/one_dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**dropdown_border.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
     <corners android:radius="6dip" />
     <stroke
         android:color="#000000"
         android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: This hasn't worked either.I assume it's just not being read into as "Android:background"

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? Just put a border on the spinner? @ChristopherMckenzie

Comment: Yeah, basically

Comment: Okay one sec. @ChristopherMckenzie

Comment: When you just use <Spinner> instead of <MaterialSpinner> the drop down border works. Do you need to have the MaterialSpinner? @ChristopherMckenzie

Comment: I'll try without MaterialSpinner

Comment: Let me know if it works for you. @ChristopherMckenzie

Comment: It seems I need to use MaterialSpinner, so I'm kinda lost now. I've figured that MaterialSpinner won't let me put the border on it I guess? Maybe?

Comment: Yeah the material spinner wont allow you to put a border. @ChristopherMckenzie